# how to confuse,compression,encryption the react native js code?

Tags: react-native

React Native JS bundle file how to confuse, compression, encryption, the existing program can not guarantee on the assets directory index.bundle file security?

React Native Is there a mechanism similar to android code confusion?

Comment: You can activate `proguard` for Android in React Native in *build.gradle*. About iOS I don't know how JS bundle is handled.

Comment: The term you're looking for is obfuscation

Comment: i want to proguard the js file，not is java code。